# How to solve error "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to find time difference between two rows. I am using `iloc` function to read time data. The code below fails with error

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/input/test.csv")
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/Raw_File/%s.csv'%newdd, parse_dates=["Date"])
del df['Unnamed: 0']
del df['???']
del df['???.1']
df1 = df.sort_index(axis=0, ascending=False)

tdelta = datetime.strptime('00:05:00', '%H:%M:%S')
tdelta1 = datetime.strptime('00:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')

flage = 0
for i in range(0, len(df1)):
    T1 = datetime.strptime(df1.iloc[i, 1], "%H:%M:%S")
    T2 = datetime.strptime(df1.iloc[i+1, 1], "%H:%M:%S")
    #print(T1-T2)
    if((T1 - T2) > (tdelta - tdelta1)):
        print('Missing Data between Time', T1, "%H:%M:%S", '&', T2, "%H:%M:%S")
        flage = flage + 1
    else:
        flage = 0
if (flage == 0):
    print("No missing Time")
```

Comment: Please post the full and complete error trace, not just the final line.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SONY/PycharmProjects/untitled/20.06.2017.py", line 41, in <module>
    T2 = datetime.strptime(df1.iloc[i+1, 1], "%H:%M:%S")
  File "C:\Users\SONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1638, in _is_valid_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: In the last iteration of your loop (when `i=len(df1)` you are trying to access the `i+1`st element which is not possible. Decrease the range to `len(df1) - 1`. Although it is not a good idea to use loops when dealing with DataFrames.

Comment: Thank you. I have applied the same and now it is working